# In React Native, how do I position and slide an element thats bigger than screen view?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flexbox

In the diagram below, each panel is the be the size of the screen and they are to slide very quickly left and right as one large element. If the slide transition is problematic its okay for time = 0 so it's instantaneous.

The contents of each panel are to stay mounted while off screen because there is a webview in the children and I want to prevent the webpage reloading (which would happen if the panel remounts). 
How do I do this? (edit: without a plugin or off the shelf navigation system)

[image: explanation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with CSS and HTML, you can probably convert it to work with React Native.

```
<html>
<header>
  <style>
  #body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200vw;
  }
  #inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background: #de9999;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #body #body-left{
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
  }
  #body #body-right{
    flex: 1 0 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgrey;
  }
</style>
</header>
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="body-left"></div>
      <div id="body-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tab navigator with swipedEnabled: true Both components will remain mounted too . Refer [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab)

An abtract example would be like this

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
  },
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
```

where home and notifications will be your components

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to code this without a plug-in or off the shelf nav system. But thanks !

Comment: Then u can use panresponder to achieve that